ThreeJS scene slows down considerably as I add objects and try to dispose of them
I'm dynamically creating a pulse wave display generator. I've taken it down to bare bones so the code is shorter. Runs really smooth when I start, but as I scrub the frequency bar the playback slows down considerably like when moving the scene left and right with the right mouse button. I'm guessing since I keep creating a new Buffer Geometry object each time I change the frequency and I'm somehow not disposing of it properly, that I end up taxing my GPU significantly. Or am I calling animate() or init() way too much? Or not disposing of my objects properly? Or is plotting 400,000 lines just way too much when I put the frequency at 100,000? Kinda new to threejs. Hoping it's something obvious.
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GUI } from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl');
let SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var scene, camera, renderer;
var frequencySuperPulse = 10000;
var startXPos, controls;
var geomSuperPulse, matSuperPulse, posSuperPulse, paSuperPulse, linesSuperPulse;;


// Camera - Scene - Renderer Initialization
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera (SCREEN_WIDTH/-2, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/-2, 150, 1000);
camera.position.z = 200;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, canvas: canvas});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// LIGHTS
const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 );
dirLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add( dirLight );

// ORBIT CONTROLS
controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enableRotate = false;
controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
controls.zoomToCursor = true;
controls.addEventListener( 'change', getControlsZoom );
var zoomResult = document.getElementById( 'zoom' );
function getControlsZoom( )
{
        zoomResult.innerHTML = 'Zoom = '+(Math.round(camera.zoom));
}

// GUI
const parameters = {
    frequencySuperPulse: frequencySuperPulse, //The second frequncy is the variable up at the top for initial value
};
function updateWaveformfrequencySuperPulse() {
    frequencySuperPulse = parameters.frequencySuperPulse;
    scene.remove(linesSuperPulse);
    geomSuperPulse.dispose();
    matSuperPulse.dispose();
    init();
}
const gui = new GUI({width: 400, title:'Laser Controls'});
const waveformoptionsSuperPulse = gui.addFolder( 'Super Pulse' );
waveformoptionsSuperPulse.add( parameters, 'frequencySuperPulse', 10000, 100000, 10000).onChange( updateWaveformfrequencySuperPulse ).name('Frequency (Hz)');
waveformoptionsSuperPulse.open();

function init() {
    // Add Super Pulse Waveform...
    geomSuperPulse = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geomSuperPulse.setAttribute("position", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(15*frequencySuperPulse), 3));
    posSuperPulse = geomSuperPulse.getAttribute("position");
    paSuperPulse = posSuperPulse.array;
    for (let line_index= 0; line_index < frequencySuperPulse; line_index++) {
        startXPos = -200 + line_index*500/frequencySuperPulse;          //Need five points to describe a cycle.
        
        //Point 1
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index] = startXPos;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+1] = 0;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+2] = 0;
        //Point 2
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+3] = startXPos;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+4] = 13000;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+5] = 0;
        //Point 3
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+6] = startXPos + 35*10**-9 * 500;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+7] = 13000;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+8] = 0;
        //Point 4
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+9] = startXPos + 35*10**-9 * 500;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+10] = 0;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+11] = 0;
        //Point 5
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+12] = startXPos + 500/frequencySuperPulse;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+13] = 0;
        paSuperPulse[15*line_index+14] = 0;
    }
    
    matSuperPulse = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
    linesSuperPulse = new THREE.Line(geomSuperPulse, matSuperPulse);
    scene.add(linesSuperPulse);
    animate();
}

function animate() {
    posSuperPulse.needsUpdate = true;
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
init();

